# How can I use the Gson to parse a json that keep the same key but not the same type

Tags: json, gson

Actually，I want to parse the json like this:

```
{
"contents": [
    {
        "type": "image", 
        "data": {
            "attachment": "picurl", 
            "width": 600, 
            "height": 398
        }
    }, 
    {
        "type": "text", 
        "data": "something like xxx"
    }
]
```

}

as you can see, the key "data" sometimes is a String, and sometings is json object, what should I do to parse this json by Gson?

Comment: How about using a custom deserializer?

Comment: I will try that way!

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is deserialize twice. First into an class that defines only `type`.

```
class TypeObject {
    public String type;
}
```

After the first deserializiation, you can read the `type`, and discover which is the real target object you should deserialize into.

De-serializing twice obviously isn't ideal, but that's the unfortunate nature of using a static language to de-serialize a JSON string with non uniform objects in a list.

Answer (score 0):

I have find the way the parse that json, as  [Alexis C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587046/alexis-c) said, I custom a deserializer, like that

```
@Override
public MessageDiv deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
    MessageDiv messageDiv = new MessageDiv();
    JsonObject obj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
    String msgtype = obj.get("type").getAsString();
    messageDiv.setType(msgtype);
    if (msgtype.equals("text")) {
        messageDiv.setContent(obj.get("data").getAsString());
    } else {
        JsonObject imgObj = obj.get("data").getAsJsonObject();
        DivData dd = new DivData();
        dd.setAttachment(imgObj.get("attachment").getAsString());
        dd.setHeight(imgObj.get("height").getAsInt());
        dd.setWidth(imgObj.get("width").getAsInt());
        messageDiv.setData(dd);
    }
    return messageDiv;
}
```

About how to custom o deserializer, click [here](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-deserialiser-example/), it's userful for me!